# Activate Federation Engine

Tags: mysql

when I checked on my sql server for federation I have got

********************* 10. row ***************************
Engine: FEDERATED
Support: NO
Comment: Federated MySQL storage engine

what is the command the enable the federation on mysql

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- You need at least MySQL version 5.0.3
- You need to start MySQL with the parameter --with-federated-storage-engine

[MySQL Federated Storage Engine Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html)